# Can I get an unspecialized vector<bool> type in C++?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

A `vector<bool>` is specialized to reduce space consumption (1 bit for each element), but it's slower to access than `vector<char>`. Sometimes I use a `vector<char>` for performance reason, but if I convert a `char` to a `bool`, my compiler (Visual C++) may generate a [C4800](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx) warning which I don't like.

Also, I think the `vector<char>` is semantically wrong if I treat it as unspecialized `vector<bool>`. So, can I get a real unspecialized `vector<bool>` type in C++?

Comment: Unfortunately, not from the standard library. Try `deque<bool>`, or `boost::container::vector<bool>`?

Comment: You may want to tell us *how* you're converting a `char` to a `bool` if it's giving you a warning.  The link you provided shows how to avoid that warning.

Comment: @DrewDormann When I return a `vector<char>`'s element in a function that returns `bool`. But I don't think it's important, because a `char` shouldn't be treat as a `bool`, although it can.

Comment: you could always create a class `Bool` that mirrors the functionality of `bool`, and have a `vector` of that.

Comment: @sp2danny: Sure, but note that `sizeof(Bool)` might not be equal to `sizeof(bool)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't get an unspecialized `std::vector<bool>`.

`vector<char>` is your best bet as you already figured out. To get around the warning, just use a bool expression:

```
bool b1 = v[0] != 0;
bool b2 = !!v[0];
```

Alternatively, create a custom bool class:

```
class Bool
{
public:
  Bool(){}
  Bool(const bool& val) : val_(val) {}
  inline Bool& operator=(const bool& val) { val_ = val; }
  operator bool() const { return val_; }

private:
  bool val_;
};
```

...

```
 vector<Bool> bvec;
 bvec.push_back(false);
 bvec.push_back(true);

 bool bf = bvec[0];
 bool bt = bvec[1];
```